# Fetch XML of Distance Matrix API (google) on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xml-parsing, gdata

I'm trying to fetch the XML data from a query to the api without success...

I'm doing this:

```
[...]

 NSURL *googleAPIurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=28.124822,-15.430006&destinations=28.126953,-15.429874|28.072056,-15.416574|28.103186,-15.417665|28.127916,-15.625403|28.099125,-15.418365|28.107740,-15.454050|28.050825,-15.454066|28.051640,-15.454104|28.101788,-15.423592|28.113750,-15.446980|28.098871,-15.420730|28.098217,-15.449371|28.083364,-15.418172&mode=driving&sensor=false"];

    NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:googleAPIurl];
    NSError *error;
    GDataXMLDocument *xmlDocument = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:&error];
    if (xmlDocument == nil) 
    {
        NSLog(@"NIL XML");
    }
[...]
```

I'm ALWAYS getting a nil XML. NSData is always nil. I don't know what is happening with this. If I use a url with one destination only it works, but not for more than one. Also, I'm using the same method to retrieve xml with google places api with no problems. This is driving me crazy...

Please point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried creating the NSData with `+ (id)dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL options:(NSDataReadingOptions)mask error:(NSError **)errorPtr` to see if you get an error? Seems likely, and it might provide some insight.

Comment: Using  xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:googleAPIurl options:NSDataReadingMapped error:&error]; i'm getting this exception: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteData initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]: nil URL argument'   Why is the url nil??? :S

Comment: Try replacing all of the `'|'` with `'%7C'`

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction! I've fixed that if you want me to accept your answers please answer this question with this line of code NSURL *googleAPIurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[distancesURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; Thanks!

Comment: I knew there was something like that, just kind of commenting my thought process. Thanks! Glad you got it fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested replacing all of the `'|'` with `'%7C'`

Turns out this is the more proper method to cover all of these character encoding issues:

```
NSURL *googleAPIurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[distancesURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```